# Why do these specific Supernatural episodes have previews?

Tags: supernatural

I'm currently working my way through the tv series *Supernatural* (currently on early season 5, watching via Netflix Streaming).  One thing that strikes me as odd is that at the end of some episodes, there is a preview of upcoming episodes (e.g. S5E5).  The word 'Soon' appears and then the preview scenes play, then the episode's end credits roll.

As I'm watching via Netflix, I assumed I was missing some context here, like these were mid-season breaks.  But, looking up this latest episode where there's a preview, there wasn't a mid-season break at this point in the season, so whatever the reason was for this specific episode to have a preview, it's not apparent to me.  In addition, since I'm watching it via Netflix Streaming, I'm not sure if these previews were so sporadic when the show aired, or maybe they were present at the end of each episode when they originally aired, and then most of them got removed as part of the editing for the Netflix version.

Why do some *Supernatural* episodes end with previews, and others don't?  Is there something special about these specific episodes that isn't immediately apparent?

Comment: I remember the releases were somewhat sporadic on the zune marketplace, but as for actual releases i couldn't tell you.  good question though!

Comment: Good question, though I can't seem to find a pattern. I'll update you if I find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opinion, but I *think* it's just a random event. It fits a pattern: the recap they almost always do has the **THEN** header. The episode is labeled **NOW**, and the rare preview is labeled **SOON**. I don't think there's anything special; they just chose for whatever reason to preview the rest of the season. I've noticed they don't only preview the next episode, but multiple episodes to follow later in the season (some a few away).

Best I can tell, it was just to whet the viewer's appetite. It's a fun show to marathon, but I'm not sure I would pay as rapt attention week to week.

Answer (score 2):

I think because during the time on tv the show was possibly on a break or hiatus. I was wondering the same thing so I think they posted the preview and the soon message so fans wouldn't think the show was over or something. Also possibly to just keep the viewers locked in because some people get bored of the same story line that lasts forever.

Comment: Per the 2nd paragraph in my question, this is not always the case.